# Mercurial push changes after local fold

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I performed a `histedit fold` on my local repo after which I tried pushing the changes to Bitbucket, but the push fails with the message:

```
remote has heads on branch 'default' that are not known locally
abort: push creates new remote head
(pull and merge or see 'hg help push' for details about pushing new heads)
```

How do I go about doing a `fold` on the remote repo without running into this problem?

Comment: Nohow without Evolve. And even with Evolve you just rewrite remote history (if remote server also support evolve - this is not true for BB)

Comment: BB supports evolve: https://blog.bitbucket.org/2017/03/28/edit-history-with-mercurial-evolve-beta-in-bitbucket-cloud/

Comment: I'd like to know why the downvote? Is the question not valid?